# React Moment problem on DatePicker when using moment (Maybe dependencies)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, components, antd

I'm using DatePicker and I can't set the default Values, I tried this:

I import the moment like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';

//And then: 

<DatePicker 
   defaultValue={moment('2015/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')}
/>

//Also tried this

<DatePicker 
   defaultValue={moment('2015/01/01')}
/>
```

But I got this error:
"Type 'import("C:/git/my_project/node_modules/moment/moment").Moment' is not assignable to type 'moment.Moment'.
 Types of property 'add' are incompatible."

I can't find where is my error

When I type npm ls moment and npm ls @types/moment. This is the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXfXr.png]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Moment' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308654/type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-moment-error)

Comment: type `npm ls moment` and `npm ls @types/moment`. You may have conflicting transitive dependencies. Also, what datepicker are you using?

Comment: I will try that, I'm using Ant Design DatePicker

Comment: I will update my question with this dependencies, what I need to do to use the correct one? Sorry, I'm new in all this things

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had multiple conflicting `moment` version. I ran `npm ls moment` and I got this:

```
├─┬ antd@4.2.2
│ ├── moment@2.25.3 
│ └─┬ rc-picker@1.4.16
│   └── moment@2.24.0  deduped
└── moment@2.24.0
```

I also had `@types/moment` installed on my repository but `moment` now supports TypeScript (You can see a deprecation warning on the [npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment))

There are the steps I followed:

```
npm un --s @types/moment
npm i --s moment@2.25.3
```

Install whatever version `antd` is dependent on to remove the errors

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot!